# Postgresql how to improve performance for large joined table sorting?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sorting, left-join

Assuming I have a query:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, sku.usd FROM product LEFT OUTER JOIN sku on product.sku_id=sku.id ORDER BY sku.usd;
```

where `product` table is a table that contains several millions rows. In this case, is there any way to add index to help sorting? Furthermore, if I have some where clause on this joined table, is there any way to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

If your db is running on hdd, you can add btree index on sku.usd and cluster your table using created index.
So you will have physically sorted rows in a table.
If you often insert data into this table then you only need to periodically cluster the table, for example, once a month.
Note that cluster command blocks the table at run time.

Comment: But it's a joined table, can Postgres create index on joined table?

Comment: Postgres can create index  and cluster product table (and also table sku).
Pre-clustering the table will at least partially replace the random access to disk with sequential during join.